# Updating multiple columns using Case

Tags: sql, oracle, query-performance

I have a query that looks like below:

```
UPDATE some_table
SET column_x = CASE WHEN x_specific_condition THEN new_value_for_x ELSE column_x END,
    column_y = CASE WHEN y_specific_condition THEN new_value_for_y ELSE column_y END, 
WHERE some_more_conditions
```

Problem with above is, each column (x, y) still gets updated with their own value if some_more_conditions return true irrespective of their specific conditions returning true. I tried removing ELSE from above, but no luck

I am combining as some_more_conditions are same for both cases, I think its better to perform all in 1 update (suggestions welcome)

Do you know if there is a way that I can perform the above update in 1 query by skipping the individual columns where the specific conditions do not match (basically avoid overwriting of same values)

Answer (score 3):

To do this in one update, you would need to expand the `where` clause:

```
UPDATE some_table
    SET column_x = CASE WHEN x_specific_condition THEN new_value_for_x ELSE column_x END,
        column_y = CASE WHEN y_specific_condition THEN new_value_for_y ELSE column_y END, 
    WHERE some_more_conditions AND
          (x_specific_condition OR
           y_specific_condition
          );
```

An alternative is to use multiple updates, but that could be more expensive:

```
UPDATE some_table
    SET column_x = new_value_for_x
    WHERE some_more_conditions AND x_specific_condition;

UPDATE some_table
    SET column_y = new_value_for_y
    WHERE some_more_conditions AND y_specific_condition;
```

Comment: About the first approach, I thought about it, the issue with that is, lets say x_specific_condition is true and y_specific_condition is false, in this case, still column_y will be updated to its own value. Cant we omit that part completely. Second approach I understand, but I want to avoid that cost (that is the main reason of this question :-))

Comment: @RachitJain . . . That's not really a big deal.  Entire records are actually updated, not individual fields in them.

Comment: actually you are right, the row is anyhow getting updated, updating one more column should not be big deal. But just thinking aloud why this feature is not given by default to leave while using CASE WHEN syntax

Comment: I read your comment again about entire record/row getting updated when a field is required to be updated. REALLY? this is new to me

Answer (score 0):

update [table_name]
set [column_name_1] = case when [column_name_1] = [condition_1] then [condition_2]
else [column_name_1]
end,
[column_name_2] = case when [column_name_2] = [condition_1] then [condition_2]
else [column_name_2]
end,
where condition;

**Note:** [table_name] is your table name, [column_name] is your column name in which you want to update values.
you can update values without where condition as well.

[find screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QM0bE.png)